# Default menu item for articles

Tags: articles, menu, default

How do I assign a default menu for all articles ?

For example, I could create a hidden menu (like "Single Article" but actually not for any single article) and use its `Itemid` at the end of each article's link.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want is possible, but if you explain what you are trying to achieve with this, I'm sure there is a way

Comment: Specifically would be interested in what format the urls should be in for you (your preference) as well as whether these urls will be generated on the site or something you use to send the urls out or post to other sites.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here though? You want a menu item to be highlighted when they view the page? Or you want to publish modules to those articles?

Comment: I want to publish special modules(related to articles) for that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to load a module for only certain articles, there are two easy ways to do this:

1. Put them all in the same category and then create a hidden menu item that loads the list of all articles in the category. No one ever needs to see the page, it just needs to exist. Then if you publish a module to that menu item, it SHOULD appear on all articles in that category (there may be times when that isn't true).
2. Put all of them in the same category, install Advanced Module manager, create your module and assign it to that category.